# CGIからのパーミッション

Tags: apache, gpio, cgi

Webから操作するリモコンカメラを作ろうとしています。

左右回転するモータドライバをGPIOでON、OFFさせる`motor_rotate.sh`をお手軽にbashで作り
所有者：グループをroot:rootとし、SUIDを付与しました。

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root  root   898 Aug  9 10:25 motor_rotate.sh
```

このスクリプトをuser権限で実行できることを確認しました。

次に、`motor_rotate.sh`を呼び出すCGI、`cam_ctl.py`をPythonで作りました。

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 190 Aug 10 07:08 cam_ctl.py
```

しかし、ブラウザからこのCGIを実行すると以下のエラーになり、

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

apache2/error.logは次のようになります。

```
/home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: 20: /home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: cannot create /sys/class/gpio/export: Permission denied
/home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: 22: /home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: cannot create /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction: Permission denied
/home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: 23: /home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: cannot create /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value: Permission denied
/home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: 34: /home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: cannot create /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value: Permission denied
/home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: 38: /home/user1/bin/motor_rotate.sh: cannot create /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value: Permission denied
[Fri Aug 10 07:41:09.833310 2018] [cgid:error] [pid 18429:tid 2985292848] [client 192.168.12.150:50335]
 End of script output before headers: cam_ctl.py, referer: http://192.168.12.103:80/
```

どのように対処したらよいでしょうか？
そもそも、CGIの実行者は誰になっているのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

ちなみに、`motor_rotate.sh`はこんな感じです（略してますので、行番号は違います）

```
#!/bin/sh
SWITCH1="/sys/class/gpio/gpio23"

if [ ! -e $SWITCH1 ]; then
    echo 23 > /sys/class/gpio/export
    sleepenh 0.1 > /dev/null
    echo out > $SWITCH1/direction
    echo 0 > $SWITCH1/value
fi

echo 1 > $SWITCH1/value
sleepenh 0.5 > /dev/null
echo 0 > $SWITCH1/value
```

追伸、AMD64版Debinaでテストしてみたんですが
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user1  user1     73  8月 10 17:01 test.py
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root   root      30  8月 10 17:00 test.sh

test.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "Hello World"
```

test.sh

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import subprocess
res = subprocess.call("./test.sh")
```

user1@debian:~$ ./test.py
Hello World

このテストでは、問題いなく動くんです、何か間違ってるのかな

Comment: raspberry piを使っていらっしゃるのだと推察いたしますが、respberryの種類、OSの種類とバージョン、webサーバの種類とバージョンといった情報を提供していただけませんか。

Comment: Raspberry 1B+、RASBIAN STRETCH LITE、apache2.4.25 です

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shスクリプトはsetuid指定が効かないと記憶しています。そのため、期待通りに動作しないと予想します。

＃shの挙動か、OS(Linux)の挙動かまでは覚えていませんが、セキュリティ対策のためです。

別のスクリプトで作成しsetuidを指定するか、スクリプトを呼び出すnative executableを作成し、それをsetuidするかすれば、期待通り動作させられるようになると思います。

＃追記の動作実験では、test.shはrootユーザでは動作していないのでは、と予想します。

Comment: 確かに、本来のテストの目的を見失っていました。test.shをtouch /etc/test.txtにすると、Permission deniedになりました。

Answer (score 0):

CGIを実行する際は基本的にApacheのユーザ権限になりますが、OSやディストリビューションの種類によって微妙に異なりますので、`httpd`プロセスがどのユーザ権限で動いているかを確認してみてください(例えばLinuxでは`apache`ユーザなことが多いです)。

ユーザが確認できたら、CGI実行時にエラーとなっているファイルが作成(書き込み)ができるよう、パーミッションを適切に設定してあげてください。

```
/sys/class/gpio/export
/sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction
/sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value
```